# minitest-rails - test:helpers - NameError: Unable to resolve controller for ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

I have strange error when i run my tests for helpers with rake test:helpers

ApplicationHelper::dummy#test_0001_must return string:
NameError: Unable to resolve controller for ApplicationHelper::dummy

Test:

```
require "test_helper"

describe ApplicationHelper do
  include ApplicationHelper
  context "dummy" do
    it "must return string" do
      result = dummy()
      result.must_be_kind_of ( String )
      result.wont_be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

My helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def dummy
    "hello world".html_safe
  end
end
```

My test_helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
require 'minitest/rg'
require "warden_mock"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  class << self
    alias :context :describe
  end
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    request.env['warden'] = WardenMock.new # mockup warden
    User.current = request.env['warden'].user
  end
  register_spec_type(/.*/, self)
end
```

rails 4.1.6
minitest-rails 2.1.0

Comment: Why are you doing this: `register_spec_type(/.*/, self)` That makes every test use ActionController::TestCase. You don't want that. Try removing it.

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution. I'm dumbass :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out `require "minitest/rails/capybara"` in your `test_helper.rb` and require it only in your feature tests